# MVC Kendo Grid multiple functions for DataBound event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How can I have multiple functions for DataBound in Kendo Grid MVC

```
events.DataBound().Events(events => events.DataBound("AdvancedGrid.onDataBound", "alertMe"));
```

so it will trig both function.

Comment: have one function that wraps multiple others?

Comment: I making C# extensions for Kendo Grid, everyone who will use it will use AdvancedGrid.js methods plus their DataBound method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through **HtmlHelper** you can't add more function to event so I look in **DOM** object found **grid** and saw that _events -> dataBound is array, so I added run this

```
var grid = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("dataBound", alertMe);
grid.dataSource.fetch();
```

and now my dataBound has 2 events

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works fine for me.

```
.Events(ev=>{ev.DataBound(@<text>function(e){ onDataBound(e); alertMe(); }</text>); })
```